# Unit testing with Mockito

Tags: spring, unit-testing, mockito

I am writing unit tests for service layer in my spring application.
Here is my service class

```
    @Service
    public class StubRequestService implements RequestService {    
        @Autowired
        private RequestDao requestDao;  

        @Transactional(propagation = Propagation.REQUIRED, readOnly = true)
        @Override
        public Request getRequest(Long RequestId) {
            Request dataRequest = requestDao.find(requestId);
            return dataRequest;
        }
    }
```

Here is my test class

```
@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(locations = { "/META-INF/spring/applicationContext.xml" })
public class StubRequestServiceTest {

    @Mock
    public RequestDao requestDao;

    StubRequestService stubRequestService;  // How can we Autowire this ?

    @org.junit.Before
    public void init() {
      stubRequestService = new StubRequestService();  // to avoid this 
      stubRequestService.setRequestDao(dataRequestDao);  
      // Is it necessary to explicitly set all autowired elements ?  
      // If I comment/remove above setter then I get nullPointerException 
    }

    @Test
    public void testGetRequest()  {
        Request request = new Request();
        request.setPatientCnt("3");
        when(requestDao.find(anyLong())).thenReturn(request);
        assertEquals(stubRequestService.getRequest(1234L).getPatientCnt(),3);
    }    
}
```

Its working fine but I have few questions

1. How can we `Autowire` service class in test ? I am using constructor in `init()` method to create service object.
2. Do we have to set all `Autowire` element for service class ? For ex  `StubRequestService` have autowired `RequestDao` which I need to set explicitly before calling test method otherwise it giveds `nullPointerException` as `requestDao` is `null` in `StubRequestService.getRequest` method.
3. Which are the good practices to follow while unit testing Spring service layer ? (If I am doing anything wrong).

Comment: If you change your question after the answers are given, the answers don't make much sense anymore. I'll rollback your last edit.

Comment: @JB: Apologies for editing question. I just wanted to provide correct and exact information. Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. If you really feel that it will make your tests easier to understand - you can initialize a spring context and fetch all of the objects from there. However, usually it will require creating a separate spring configuration XML file specifically for tests therefore I would not recommend it.

   ```
   ApplicationContext applicationContext = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("testApplicationContext.xml");
   stubRequestService = (RequestService)applicationContext.getBean("myRequestServiceBean");
   ```
2. (and 3) Basically, I prefer testing each component of my application in total isolation from eachother and that's why I do not recommend what I described in [1].

What that means, is you take a separate logical slice of your application and test **only** it, while **fully** mocking up everything it tries to access.

Let's say you have three classes:

```
//Fetches stuff from some webservice and converts to your app domain POJOs
class DataAccessLayer {
    public void setWebservice(Webservice ws) {...};

    public MyObject getMyObject() {...};
}

//Formats the domain POJOs and sends them to some kind of outputstream or stuff.
class ViewLayer {
    public void setOutputStream(OutputStream os) {...};

    public void viewMyObject(MyObject mo) {...};
}

//Main entry point of our MyObject fetch-process-display workflow
class Controller {
    public void setDataAccessLayer(DataAccessLayer dal) {...};
    public void setViewLayer(ViewLayer vl) {...};

    public void showMyObject() {
        MyObject mo = dal.getMyObject();
        ...some processing here maybe...
        vl.viewMyObject(mo);
    }
}
```

Now, what tests can we write here?

1. Test if `DataAccessLayer` properly converts the object from *mocked up* WS to our domain object.
2. Test if `ViewLayer` properly formats the object given to him and writes it to *mocked up* output stream.
3. Test if `Controller` takes an object from *mocked up* `DataAccessLayer` processes it properly and sends it to *mocked up* `ViewLayer`.

Comment: Is there specific reason to use different context file to instantiate bean in test ? And thanks for example. It really helped a lot.

Comment: There is no reason, it's just that it usually happens that it is incompatible with your tests. For example it requires some JNDI resources, maybe loads some databases (and tests never use them), maybe some security. So in the end you simply start noticing that it's easier to create a separate context file for testing.

Comment: Yes, there is a reason: you don't want to test a service with the real DAO. You want a mock DAO to test the service. But follow Max's advice and mine: don't use a Spring context to unit test services. You might want a Spring context to inject a Datasource, SessionFactory and TxManager in DAO tests, but not in service tests.

Comment: @JBNizet Well, sometimes using spring context in tests is worth it. For example when you are doing integration tests of some large component that depends on some specific configuration.

Comment: @Max: yes, that's what I'm suggesting in my previous comment. It's useful when testing DAOs, for example, which depend on a database, TxManager, etc. For pure business services, it shouldn't be needed.

Comment: You should never need to manage an application context yourself in tests unless testing infrastructure code. Instead, use the [Spring Test Framework](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/testing.html).

Answer (score 7):

Your test is fine. It doesn't even have to have the `@ContextConfiguration` annotation.

The whole point of dependency injection frameworks like Spring is to be able to unit test services by simply instantiating them, setting mock dependencies, and then call their methods.

You're doing it correctly. You don't need to have a Spring context for such unit tests. That's why they're called unit tests: they test it in isolation of all their actual dependencies, Spring included.

Side note: assuming you're using JUnit, the arguments of the assertXxx method should be swapped. The expected value comes before the actual value. It becomes important when the assertion fails and you have a message like "expecting 6 but was 3" rather than "expecting 3 but was 6".

Comment: Thanks for answer and suggestion. Is it mean that we should explicitly create service object and set all autowired dependency ? I am being advised to autowire it instead of setting it manually.

Comment: Autowiring is OK when running the application. It's not needed, or even desired, when unit testing, since every test will want to inject its own mocked dependencies.

Answer (score 3):

Or You can use springockito
https://bitbucket.org/kubek2k/springockito/wiki/Home, it will make your tests cleaner